# Selected option from drop down bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap with RAILS. My goal is to:

1. build "bootstraped" drop down list
2. display select item in `<p>`, `<div>` or `<span>`

JavaScript looks like:

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
      $("#chosen").text($(this).text());      
   });
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="container">        
  <h2>Choose</h2>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">szablony
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
        <% @books.each do |book| %>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                    <%= book.name %>
                </a>
            </li>
        <% end %>              
    </ul>
  </div>      
  <p id="chosen"></p>      
</div>
```

The problem is that after selecting option, selected text in `<p id="chosen">` appears only for a split second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your html:

```
<div class="container">        
  <h2>Choose</h2>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">szablony
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
        <% @books.each do |book| %>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void();">
                    <%= book.name %>
                </a>
            </li>
        <% end %>              
    </ul>
  </div>      
  <p id="chosen"></p>      
</div>
```

Comment: @KilgoreTrout can you please mark my answer as useful